# How to remove every nth byte from a byte array?

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have a byte array like

```
 byte[] bytes = {69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, 195, 61, 101, 98};
```

How can I remove every nth byte from this byte array? If n = 3 then result should be every multiple of 3 ( starting from index 0 => 3, 6 ,9 12 and so on). So 45, 101, 61.. nth.

Do I need to use System.arraycopy with a new holder array?

Comment: You can't remove anything from a byte array. You can only replace the value stored at a given index by another value. If you want to create a new array, with all the original values except some, then do just that. If you know about loops, division and the modulo operator, this should be easy enough. Try something.

Comment: Please show us some effort and btw. this isn't even a valid byte array.

Comment: `195` can't be added to `byte` array, max value for byte is `127`.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: To answer to "Do I need to use System.arraycopy with a new holder array?": No.  You specifically need **not to use** `System.arraycopy`.  `System.arraycopy` is for copying a  _block_ of elements; you need to copy individual elements one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

First, YOU must try to put some effort in coding and show us the result of your trying so we can help you...

That code will give you a new array without the nth elements:

```
    byte[] bytes = { 69, 121, 101, 45, 62, 118, 101, 114, 127, 61, 101, 98 };
    int n = 3;
    List<Byte> byteList = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    for (int i = 0, j = n; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if (i == j) {
            j += n;
            continue;
        }
        byteList.add(bytes[i]);
    }

    // if you want to return the code to a byte[]
    byte[] newByte = new byte[byteList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println( byteList.get(i));
        newByte[i] = byteList.get(i);
    }

   // Or you can use toArray method 
   // Byte[] newByteArray = byteList.toArray(new Byte[byteList.size()]);
```

Sample output:

```
69
121
101
62
118
114
127
101
98
```

Comment: I guess this is not what OP wanted. He would like to remove every nth byte from a byte array. not to acquire data every nth byte from a byte array instead.